# given/when with undefined value

Tags: perl, warnings, initialization

In the following code, I get an `uninitialized value` warning, but only in the second `given/when` example. Why is this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;

my $aw;

given ( $aw ) {
    when ( 'string' ) { 
        say "string"; 
    }
    when ( not defined ) { 
        say "aw not defined"; 
    }
    default { 
        say "something wrong"; 
    }
}

given ( $aw ) {
    when ( /^\w+$/ ) { 
        say "word: $aw"; 
    }
    when ( not defined ) { 
        say "aw not defined";
    }
    default { 
        say "something wrong";
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
aw not defined
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./perl.pl line 20.
aw not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`given`/`when`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Experimental-Details-on-given-and-when) uses the "[smartmatch operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator)": `~~`.

`undef ~~ string` is:

```
undef     Any        check whether undefined
                     like: !defined(Any)
```

Thus there is no warning here.

`undef ~~ regex` is:

```
 Any       Regexp     pattern match                                     
                      like: Any =~ /Regexp/
```

And a warning is produced when trying to match on `undef`.

Comment: So he should put the `defined` check at the top to fix this?

Comment: @simbabque, yes that would remove the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `when (EXPR)` usually equal `when ($_ ~~ EXPR)`. And `undef ~~ 'string'` is `!defined('string')` so you don't get warning, but `undef ~~ /regexp/` is `undef =~ /regexp/` so you get warning.

See [Switch Statements in `perlsyn`](http://metacpan.org/module/perlsyn#Switch-Statements) and [Smartmatch Operator in `perlop`](http://metacpan.org/module/perlop#Smartmatch-Operator).